# Need to build a direct graph on networkx(Python)

Tags: python, networkx, tweepy

On a json serialization, I have to create a direct graph and for every follower of my "target analysis account" I have to create an edge on the direct graph.

Specifically, I have to analyze a twitter account which has 135 followers. For each follower of the account, I have to create a sort of connection with the accounts who follow it, and in the end, create the whole network.

The connections are based on twitter "id" and are all placed in a .json file (already done)

Thanks

```
#building a direct graph
directed_graph = nx.DiGraph()
directed_graph.add_node("Maintwitteraccount")

for follower in all_user_follower.data:
    directed_graph.add_node(follower["id"], username=follower["username"], description=follower["description"], follower_count=follower["public_metrics"]["followers_count"])
    directed_graph.nodes(data = True)


print("Questi sono i nodi:\n",directed_graph.nodes())
#print(directed_graph.nodes().data())

with open('data/followers.json', encoding="utf8") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

with open('data/followers_serializzati.json', encoding="utf8") as json_file:
    data2 = json.load(json_file)

# Building edges from maintwitteraccount and his followers
i=0     
while i < len(all_followers[username]):
    id = data['Maintwitteraccount'][i]['id']
    directed_graph.add_edge("Maintwitteraccount",id)
    i += 1

#building edges from followers of  Maintwitteraccount and their followers
i=0
j=0
while i < len(all_followers[username]):    
    id = data['Maintwitteraccount'][i]['id']
    
    follower_count_id = data2[str(id)]['public_metrics']['followers_count']

    while j < min(follower_count_id,1000):
        follower_id = list(data2[str(id)]['followers'].keys())[j]
        directed_graph.add_edge(id,follower_id)
        j += 1
       
    i += 1


print("\nQuesti sono gli archi:\n",directed_graph.edges())
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: hi, i dont know how to create a direct graph, cause only  "# Building edges from maintwitteraccount and his followers" works....

Comment: You'll need to do this recursively, right?  If Joe is connected to Bill, Ted and Sam, you'll have to call a recursive function to fill in the followers for Bill, Ted and Sam.

Comment: How are the json files formatted?  In `NetworkX`, you don't need to create a node before creating edges - if you list two nodes to create an edge and the nodes don't already exist in the graph, they will be created along with the edge.  So if you have some sort of list of follower ids for each user id, adding all of the edges in the network should be relatively straightforward and will create corresponding nodes as needed.